# A dealer professes to sell his goods at cost price, but he uses a false weight and gains $\frac{300}{47}\%$. For a kg he uses a weight of?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A dealer professes to sell his goods at cost price, but he uses a false weight and gains $\frac{300}{47}\%$. For a kg he uses a weight of
>
> a. $953$g
>
> b. $960$g
>
> c. $940$g
>
> d. $947$g
>
> e. $936$g

If the cost price of the dealer is $1000$, the selling price is $x$, and I get:

$$\frac{x-1000}{1000} \cdot 100=\frac{300}{47}$$

However, the value of $x$ is not correct. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What does "gain $300/47$" mean?

Comment: If the dealer is making gains then he is selling less weight than he claims to be. Therefore, the equation to solve should be $$\frac{1000-x}{1000}\times 100=\frac{300}{47}$$

Comment: @onlymaths In the OP $x$ is the sales price. Nominally this means $x\text\kg$ (or any other unit of weight, but kg is what is used in the problem). But actually this means $x\text\\(y\text{ grams})$ (where $y < 1000$). We know sales price is inflated by $300\over 47 %$, so how much must $y$ be decreased to yield the inflation? In other words $y=\frac{1kg}{1+\frac3{47}}=940 \text{ grams}$. This matches jvdhooft's answer. So your approach was on track, but you solved for dollars, instead of kg. (Dollars and kg are inversely proportional in this problem)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the gain is in percentage, so a gain of $\frac{3}{47}\% \approx 6.38\% = 0.0638$. This means that for every $47g$ sold, the dealer gains the value of an extra $3g$ worth of merchandise. For $1kg$, the dealer must thus use a weight of:

$$\frac{47}{50}kg = 940g$$

Note that this can also be derived as follows, with $x$ the shortage of weight in grams for every $1kg$:

$$\frac{x}{1000-x} = \frac{3}{47} \iff 47x = 3000 - 3x \iff x = \frac{3000}{50} = 60$$

Comment: From where did this equation come? $x/1000-x$ @jydhooft

Comment: @onlymaths The dealer charges you for $1kg$ instead of for $(1000-x)g$. As such, for every $(1000-x)g$ he sells, he makes an additional profit equivalent to the value of $x g$ worth of merchandise. The ratio of the two is his additional gain, which equals $\frac{3}{47}$.